Remove Message from Network using CAPL
I'm new on CAPL, and I'm trying to do a sequence where a "key" is pressed and after this, I'll be able to remove a msg from network. My code actual is:
on key 'a' {
  TestEnableMsg(DM01_ECM);
}

I'm receiving the forward error
Status  Compiling file 'ECM.can'    ECM.can
Error     1159 at (34,3): function is not allowed within the current context (CANalyzer, Analyze, Test ...).    ECM.can
    Compilation failed (11:23:36) -- 1 errors, 0 warnings   ECM.can


the real code it was  on key 'a'
{
TestEnableMsg(DM01_ECM);}

As the error message tells you the method testEnableMsg ( as all other methods starting with test...) can only be used in a testing context, i.e. in a test module or test unit. Not in a key-handler. Are you looking for ILDisableMsg?

long TestDisableMsg (dbMsg aMessage);
isables the sending of the message except by calling the function TestSetMsgEvent. Use TestEnableMsg to re-enable the message

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
